# Diretiva para restringir digitação com expressão regular no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directives

Eu escrevi uma diretiva para inibir a digitação a partir da especificação de uma regex. No entanto há dois bugs nessa solução:

1. No primeiro [exemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QK9ZPcuESuXEsht1csyb?p=preview)  o input deve permitir **somente números** ou **números seguidos de ponto [.]**, ou **números seguidos de ponto seguido de números com não mais que 4 dígitos**.

   - Se eu digito *'1.1111'* e vou para o início do campo e digito outro digito (com o objetivo de ter o valor *'11.1111'*) , nada acontece. Este bug ocorre devido ao fato de eu usar a expressão `elem.val() + event.key` no meu validador (utilizei pois não sei como recuperar o valor corrente do input);
2. O segundo é o fato de alguns caracteres (crase, agudo, til, circumflexo) estarem sendo permitidos (pressione qualquer um deles mais de uma vez no campo), embora a regex não os permita.

**Quais mudanças eu tenho que fazer no meu código para ter uma restrição efetiva a partir de regex?**

```
  <html ng-app="app">    
  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.4" data-semver="1.6.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Restrict typing by RegExp</h1>
    PATTERN 1 (^\d+$|^\d+[.]$|^\d+[.]\d{1,4}$) <input type="text" allow-typing="^\d+$|^\d+[.]$|^\d+[.]\d{1,4}$"/><br>
    ONLY NUMBERS <input type="text" allow-typing="^[0-9]+$"/><br>
    ONLY STRINGS <input type="text" allow-typing="^[a-zA-Z]+$"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('allowTyping', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var regex = attrs.allowTyping;
      elem.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        var input = elem.val() + event.key;
        var validator = new RegExp(regex);
        if(!validator.test(input)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Testei seu exemplo no Plunker e não foi possível inserir caracteres especiais (crase, agudo, til, circumflexo).

Comment: Estranho que eu consigo, tanto no Firefox quanto no Chrome.

Comment: Não consegui inserir diretamente pelo teclado, mas consegui com `Ctrl+C` e `Ctrl+V`. Após inserir estes caracteres com copiar e colar, a caixa de input trava e não é possível inserir mais caracteres.

Comment: Hum... bem lembrado. Tenho que resolver isso também.

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver o problema (2) dos diacríticos:

```
<input type="text" allow-typing="^[A-zÀ-ÿ]+$"/>
```

Para resolver o problema (1) use timeout e compara o valor pré e pós keydown.
Mas ainda permite colar valores errados, use *onfocus*/*onclick* + *onchange* para a comparação.

```
var regex = attrs.allowTyping;
var prevValue = elem.val();

elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
  var validator = new RegExp(regex);
  var prevValue = this.value;

  setTimeout(function () {
    if (!validator.test(elem.val()))
      elem.val(prevValue);
  }, 1)
});

elem.bind('focus click', function(event) {
  var prevValue = this.value;
});

elem.bind('change', function(event) {
  var validator = new RegExp(regex);

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(prevValue, elem.val())
    if (!validator.test(elem.val()))
      elem.val(prevValue);
  }, 1)
});
```

Comment: no change porque não fazer um replace englobando os caracteres não autorizados, substituindo eles por ""?

Comment: Mais por segurança mesmo eliminei toda a entrada inválida, porque os RegExp dele tem limites de início e fim. No caso de somente números ou letras precisa somente eliminar `^` e `$`, mas expressões mais complexas pode levar a geração de bugs em casos não pensados.